# obtener link de una busqueda en php

Tags: php, regex

estoy haciendo un validador en php inicialmente con una función simple.

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$estado;
$amp = file_get_contents("$url");
$buscar = "/amp";
$resul = strpos($amp, $buscar);
if($resul!= false){
    $estado= 'La página existe!';
}else{
    $estado= 'La página no existe :(';
}

echo $estado;
```

lo que hace la función es buscar en el código de una página esta etiqueta

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://dominio.com/amp/version-mobil-de-la-pagina">
```

si lo encuentra quiere decir que esa pagina tiene una versión de amp disponible.
pero me gustaria que ademas me arroje unicamente el link de esa version, es decir:

```
https://dominio.com/amp/version-mobil-de-la-pagina
```

no tengo idea como implementarlo quizás con expresiones regulares, pero no se como empezar, se agradece de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con lo siguiente, que no es más que buscar específicamente la url con el formato que buscas dentro del contenido de tu página. Si lo encuentra muestra el texto satisfactorio y el listado de todas las que encontró.

```
$url = $_POST['url'];   
$estado;
$amp = file_get_contents($url);
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/https?:\/\/.+\/amp\/[^"\']+/', $data, $matches);
if(count($matches) > 0){
    echo "La pagina existe <br />";
    print_r(array_shift($matches));
} else {
    echo "La pagina no existe.";
}
```

Comment: y si la página tuviera una sección adicional como 'https://dominio.com/amp/otraseccion/version-mobil-de-la-pagina' como seria el cambio?

Comment: Sigue funcionando el solo busca que tenga http://algo/amp/otra_cosa/u_otra o https://algo/amp/otra_cosa/u_otra

Comment: tienes razón... no me funcionaba pero cambié algunas variables, y funciono perfecto, en general fue excelente.. gracias por eso